# unchecking HTML checkbox using perl Mojolicious

Tags: perl, mojolicious

How can I uncheck a checkbox by default using perl Mojolicious?
what I currently have checks the box by default and sets the value to 1:

```
%= check_box employed => 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you show does not check the checkbox by default.

`check_box 'employed' => 1` renders a checkbox with `name` set to `employed` and `value` set to `1`. Whether it is rendered in checked state depends on the `employed` param.

Perhaps you are seeing that Mojolicious picks up the `employed` param from the request and uses its value to render the checkbox accordingly (which is default behavior).

If you don't want that, you can reset the param to a false value to always render the box unchecked:

```
use Mojolicious::Lite -signatures;
use Data::Dumper;

any '/testform' => sub ($c) {
    print Dumper($c->param('option'));
    # reset (render unchecked):
    $c->param(option=> 0);
    $c->render(template => 'testform');
};
app->start;

__DATA__
@@ testform.html.ep

%= form_for testform => begin
  %= check_box 'option'=> 1
  %= submit_button
% end
```